# If blood speaks, DNA is its voice

Tags: translation-check, syntax

I'm trying to come up with a motto that pays homage to my forensic background. I'm considering sanguis ipso loquitor. Before I carve it into wood, I want to make sure I've not blundered grammatically.

Comment: Can you add what you think *sanguis ipso loquitur* (not *loquitor*) is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

> DNA vox sanguinis

This literally means just "DNA, the voice of blood." It's not a literal translation of what you asked, but it's in the pithy style of Latin mottos. The brevity also makes the metaphor of the voice quite prominent. In Latin, you can omit the linking verb, so this also means "DNA is the voice of blood."

Perhaps there's a way to translate "DNA" into Latin, but I think just using the acronym, which comes from Greek and Latin roots, is both appropriate and clear in a modern context.

Comment: it looks good but the use of the acronym like that looks a bit off, as anyone from SPQR could tell you

Comment: @MichaelWolf Hmm, maybe [Wiktionary](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidum_desoxyribonucleicum) can help here. For _acidum deoxyribonucleicum_ it suggests either DNA or ADN.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe "Si sanguis loquitur, DNA vox eius est."?

Comment: Can you expand on this, specifically with regard to Latin's conditional sentence structure and sequence of tenses?